# Laravel accessing multiple models/tables in a single view

Tags: php, laravel, models, laravel-blade

So I am building a website in the Laravel framework for Project Management.
Buy my problem is: I have a Models table, a submodels table and a subsubmodelstable. and the submodels belong to a model and a subsubmodel belongs to a submodel. But I want to have some kind of dashboard view where I can oversee all the modules with their submodules and the subsubmodules of those. 
But I am having trouble accessing all the models(tables) in my dashboard view.
I have controllers for al the module types but none yet for the dashboard view.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way will be to [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) models with both relations:

```
Model::with('submodel', 'submodel.subsubmodel')->get();
```

Dot notation is used for [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) here.

Comment: I'm sorry but where do I put that exactly? even with the docs I'm having problems

Comment: You need to put this in controller or in a model (in this case, you should a bit modify the code). It's better to read some good Laravel tutorial or watch some introduction videos first.

Answer (score 0):

if you can get the submodels from the model like $model->submodels, then you can just create a controller for your dashboard, and return the dashboard view with the model

```
$models = Model::all();
$return view('...')->with('models', $models);
```

in the view, iterate over all models. In the iteration, you can also iterate over its submodels and its subsubmodels

```
@foreach($models as $model)
    @foreach($model->submodels as $submodel)
        @foreach($submodel->subsubmodels as $subsubmodel)

        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: When I try do call them like $model->submodels it just prints "submodels ?>" on the page

Comment: in the  model, have you defined a function submodels(){return $this->hasMany(Submodel::class);} ?

[Laravel relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)
edit: fixed typing error

Comment: Alright I it written down as 'public function submodules(){ return $this->hasMany('App\Submodule'); }' and I got passed the error but then I got this error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'submodules.module_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `submodules` where `submodules`.`module_id` = 1 and `submodules`.`module_id` is not null) (View: D:\Program Files\wamp\www\pmsl\resources\views\module\index.blade.php).
it now tried to acces submodules.module_id but it needs to acces submodules.modules_id